# How to fix apache server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

After reintalling mysql-server due to a crash. I cannot get apache2 up running again when i

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I get this error

```
 Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
```

Output of config test was:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 142 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load:
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server:
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory

Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: is your `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so` exists?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Then restart apache2.